# Elastic Scale / Pulse Animation with flutter_animate Package

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to reproduce the animation shown on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57573216/1142348).

[image]

I am trying to use the [flutter_animate package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate) instead of `ScaleTransition` because I want to be able to trigger the animation with a `ValueNotifier<double>` that I control in my state management code.

Here is a reusable widget that I've created so far:

```dart
class WPulse extends StatelessWidget with WatchItMixin {
  final Widget child;
  final ValueNotifier<double> pulse;
  final Function? done;

  const WPulse({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.pulse,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //~~~
    watchValue((UI model) => model.pulseChats);
    //~~~
   
    return child
        .animate(
          target: pulse.value,
          onComplete: (controller) {
            pulse.value = 0.0;
          },
        )
        .scale(
          begin: const Offset(0.8, 0.8),
          end: const Offset(1.0, 1.0),
          duration: 800.ms,
          delay: 0.ms,
          curve: Curves.elasticInOut,
        ); // scale up
  }
}
```

My `pulse` value is passed into the widget and points back to my `ChangeNotifier` class like this:

```dart
class UI with ChangeNotifier {
  final pulseChats = ValueNotifier<double>(0);
}
```

I can change `pulseChats` anywhere in my app and it will trigger this animation. I want the unread badge to pulse like the aforementioned Stack Overflow question whenever the number changes.

Here is a gif that shows what I have so far:

[image]

I can't seem to solve a few things:

1. I want the badge to start at a `1.0` scale and return to a `1.0` scale, but if I don't start or end with something different, then nothing animates.
2. There's a bit of a delay from when the number changes (and the `ValueNotifier` is set) to when the animation actually happens.
3. There isn't enough springy bounce animation with `Curves.elasticInOut`.

Has anyone pulled off an animation like this using `flutter_animate`? I'd be most grateful for some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: I ended up using a simpler animation that was a little easier to control with my state logic. But yes, these solutions were very insightful. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

@Clifton Labrum Please take a look at [badges](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) package. It offers a wide range of animations and allows for customizing badges. I believe this could be very helpful!